# A connected $k$-regular graph of order 12 is embedded in the plane, resulting in eight regions.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

> A connected $k$-regular graph of order $12$ is embedded in the plane, resulting in eight regions. What is $k$?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having answering this question?

Comment: I just didn't think to use the handshaking lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Euler's characteristic formula $f-e+v=2$ for a planar graph. So by the information given we have $8-e+12=2$. Then using the number of edges, the handshaking lemma, and the fact that the graph is $k$-regular, we can find $k$.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks so much! Just figured it out thanks to your help. I used Euler's characteristic and got m=18. Then I used the handshaking lemma to get the degree total, which was 2*18 = 36. Finally since the order was 12 I used the fact that 12k = 36 since we are k regular and got k=3  !

Comment: $k=3$ sounds correct.